# how to store access token for facebook in social auth

Tags: android, facebook, integration, socialauth

I am using social auth for integration of social app like facebook, google and many more. I successfully authorized and access token is printed in logcat but i want to store them for send to api.

```
class SignUp extends Activity
{
  SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
  public void onCreate(Bundle SavedBundleInstanceState )
  { 
   adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
   adapter.authroize(SignUp.this,Provider.Facebook);

  }
```

By This code i get the access token in logcat but dont know how to store it.

Comment: You can use many storage options from android like Shared Preferences,SQLite Databases etc  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @Mourice u r not getting my question..actually by above code i am able to print access token on logcat but don,t know how to get them into my activity so i can use them ..i have use social auth for integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go with most easiest way `shared preferences` .. or use `session`... where you can save and retrieve `string` with `key value`..

SessionManager.java

```
 public class SessionManager {
// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "wlm";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
private static final String STATUS = "status";
private static final String STATUS_COLOR = "status_color";



// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

// Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}   

/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 * */
public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        //           Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginScreen.class);
        //           // Closing all the Activities
        //           i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //            
        //           // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        //           i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //            
        //           // Staring Login Activity
        //           _context.startActivity(i);
    }

}

/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // user name
    user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

    // user email id
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
    //       Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginScreen.class);
    //       // Closing all the Activities
    //       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //        
    //       // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    //       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //        
    //       // Staring Login Activity
    //       _context.startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * Quick check for login
 * **/
// Get Login State
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
```

}

in you activity you can store you string with

```
session.editor.putInt("your key", YourString);
```

and retrieve with

```
String str = session.pref.getString("your key", "");
```

also define key for every entry in SessionManager like

```
 private static final String ANY_NAME= "your key";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acess token is stored in Session class

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
String accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
```